# C# AES PKCS #7 wrong padding bytes?

Tags: c#, aes, padding, pkcs#7

I have set up a simple symmetric AES-en/decryption in C#, but I'm having problems with the padding. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librar/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.aspx), the padding bytes for PKCS #7 are supposed to be `0x07`, but in my case it's just zero-bytes (`0x00`).

**How is this possible?** It almost seems as if this was not correctly implemented in .NET...

Here is my code:

```
Aes aes = new AesManaged();
aes.Key = new byte[] { /* ...  */ };
aes.IV = new byte[] { /* ... */ };
// Debugging shows:
// aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

// the data to encrypt (1 byte only, to demonstrate padding)
byte[] plainData = new byte[1] { 0xFF };
byte[] encData;

// (encrypt)
using (MemoryStream encStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cryptoStream.Write(plainData, 0, plainData.Length);
    }
    encData = encStream.ToArray();
}

// (new length is 16 bytes (128 bits), incl. padding)
plainData = new byte[16];

// (decrypt)
using (MemoryStream decrStream = new MemoryStream(encData))
{
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(decrStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        cryptoStream.Read(plainData, 0, plainData.Length);
    }
}

// output:
// 16 bytes,
// 1st byte = 0xFF,
// other 15 bytes = 0x00 (instead of 0x07!)
```

Comment: Can you please not stack your question title with keywords? It isn't necessary - that is what the tags section is for. Can you take some time and edit it to something that's readable?

Comment: Make a suggestion, I don't know what else to choose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The decryptor is correctly removing the padding that was applied by the encryptor, thus the zero bytes in your output are simply the un-touched bytes in the original `plainData` array. The `cryptoStream.Read(...)` call returns an integer indicating the number of bytes that were read (`1` in this case), which you should be using to determine how many bytes in the output array are valid data.

If for whatever reason you are interested in seeing the padding bytes, you can set `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;` *after* the encryption is performed, but *before* you create the decryptor. You will then find that `cryptoStream.Read(...)` returns `16`, and `plainData` has `0xff` as its first byte, followed by 15 bytes of `0x0f` padding (not sure why your question indicates you were expecting `0x07` though).

Comment: That makes absolute sense! I must have been blind... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For PKCS7 mode it should be `blocksize - contentsize`, i.e. 16 - 1 = 15 in your case. Your mistake is that you expect it after decryption but padding happens internally before encryption. There are no guarantees that `plainData` will contain padded bytes according to mode choosen.